# JavaDoc errors, publishing my first documentation

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm attempting to "compile" my java documentation for my project and receiving the following error(and about twenty more of it's type.)

```
error: reference not found
 * {@link TCPServer} instance, The UDP Server is not configured for stand-alone
```

I then tried to link it by going through it's packaging, like so:

```
error: reference not found
 * {@link net.framework.net.tcp.TCPServer} instance, The UDP Server is not configured for stand-alone
```

After reading the JavaDoc guides again, I don't see what I'm missing, anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you try to add `import net.framework.net.tcp.TCPServer;`?

Comment: Where does the `import net.framework.net.tcp.TCPServer` class come from? Is it a part of your project or an 3rd party?

Comment: @Eran, thanks, adding the import worked perfectly, strange that eclipse doesn't auto-import it when it's required in the JDoc.

Comment: @Mureinik - It's part of my project, it's a huge networking api.

Comment: @Christian.tucker Great. Since it worked, I wrote an answer.

Comment: @Eran - I was waiting for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
add import net.framework.net.tcp.TCPServer;
```

to the class that has that `@link`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `{@link }` JavaDoc construct you must either have an import statement for the class you are linking to or use a fully qualified class name (class name including the package).

Comment: would the "package" include the `src` folder? Because in my question I wrote out the full package path.